# Solve differential equation: $f'''(x)=f(x)f'(x)f''(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I came across $f'''(x)=f(x)f'(x)f''(x)$ but I don't know how to solve it.

I tried

$\frac{f'''(x)}{f''(x)}=f(x)f'(x)$

$\ln|f''(x)|=\frac{1}{2}f(x)^2+c_{1}$

But from there I have no idea how to proceed.

Please help me solve this if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After

$$
f'' = C_0e^{\frac 12 f^2}
$$

we have

$$
f'' f' = C_0e^{\frac 12 f^2}f'\Rightarrow \frac 12(f')^2=C_0\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\phi\left(\frac{f}{\sqrt 2}\right)+C_1
$$

with

$$
\phi\left(x\right)=\int_0^x e^{\zeta^2}d\zeta
$$

and finally we arrive to the solution after integrating

$$
\frac{df}{\sqrt{2\left(C_0\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\phi\left(\frac{f}{\sqrt 2}\right)+C_1\right)}} = dx
$$

Comment: Wow. That's pretty elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Just a clarity question: with respect to what variable does one integrate the last expression? Edit: It's x, right?

Comment: @clathratus The last expression was obtained due to the variable separation property. So the result should be $F(f) = x + C_2$ which gives an implicit solution for $f(x)$

Comment: Okay thank you.